# Old WW2 game played with cards instead of a board

Tags: identify-this-game

I don't have a ton of information, but maybe it's enough to help me out?  Played it a few times MANY years ago, was a lot of fun.

It's a WW2 game played without a board.  I remember playing as the Russians, and my friend who owned the game played as the Germans.  I think it may have been possible to play as others, but not 100% sure.  It's quite old and out of print, early 80's or older... think Avalon Hill in their hay day (although I don't think it was made by Avalon Hill, but it's possible).

Does anyone have any clue what I'm talking about?  would love to try to pick up a copy of it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

[Up Front](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/586/front)?

Old 1980s Avalon Hill card game with Russians, Germans, and US in the base game and lots of expansions.  Recently funded for republishing on [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1325766284/up-front-the-card-game).

Comment: That Kickstarter may or may not happen.  I think there are still (multiple?) lawsuits pending.